# Event listener for multiple embedded SVGs

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I have a  page with multiple SVGs that are embedded like this:

```
<object data="/path" type="image/svg+xml" id="index"></object>
```

Each SVG represents a graph and is supposed to execute a function when a node is clicked. So far, I use the following code snippet for a single SVG.

```
var oTag = document.getElementById('index'); // get object tag
var svgDoc = oTag.contentDocument; // get DOM of SVG

$(svgDoc).on('click', function(event) {...
```

I there a way to make the code dynamic to handle multiple SVGs?

Comment: `$("object").each(function() { $(this.contentDocument).click(function(e) {...}); });`

Answer (score 1):

take a look ate this fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/uttwhh1a/

hope it help

```
$('.test').each(function(){
     $(this).on('click', 
          function(event) {
              alert($(this).attr('value'));
          }
     );
});
```